# How can I easily combine multiple Excel columns to a single columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a dataset which has a seven possible conditions based on data in other columns. I had to split my formulae for those conditions across seven different columns. I would like to combine all seven of those condition columns into a single column.

CONSIDER:

```
Col A  Col B  Col C  Col D  Col E  Col F  Col G  result
case1                                            case1
                            case5                case5   
       case2                                     case2    
                                   case6         case6
case1                                            case1   
                     case4                       case4    
              case3                              case3 
                                   case6         case6 
                                          case7  case7
                     case4                       case4
              case3                              case3
```

There will NEVER be a case where there are two values assigned to the same row. I just want to get the ONE data value that occurs in that row to show up in a single column. I could do `if(a<>" ",a,if(b<>" ",b,etc...` but I'm looking for something simple and elegant. The best I've been able to come up with so far is `TRIM(CONCATENATE(A+B+C+D+E+F+G))` but I was wondering if there were a simpler function (like `MERGEALLCOLUMNSINTOONE(A:G)` that would do this?

Comment: Note that syntax for concatenating string values would be TRIM(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1)), i.e., not using the "+" signs, which would throw an error. Of course, if your case values were numeric, you  could just use SUM(A1:G1), for example.

Comment: simply `TRIM(A & B .... G)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraint that there is only one value per set of cells then I think the `TRIM(CONCATENATE))` option is your best bet. It's kind of elegant in it's own way.

Comment: It's anything but elegant. It's clunky (technical term :-)). Concatenate() never adds value. It can always be replaced by just using the & operator. You save eleven letters and two braces. Trim(A1&B1&C1...&G1) does the same thing, but shorter. Elegant can be done, but not with Concatenate().

Answer (score 5):

The Trim/Concatenate combo will always return text, even if the actual value is numeric. This formula will return the value with its respective data type retained.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:G2<>""),A2:G2)
```

Assuming data starts in row 2 and row 1 has labels. Copy down.

Comment: This may come in handy. Right now, the values are all text, so I'm not terribly worried about it, but as we all know, requirements change. :) good one for the toolbox.